# Lithium polymer battery numbering

Tags: lithium-polymer

Lithium polymer accumulators has 6 numbers on it. For example accumulator on the following image has 350830. What does this number stands for?

[image: Li-pol accumulator 350830]

Comment: Most likely a code use by the manufacturer to be able to trace the data and/or batch of production.

Comment: I have multiple peaces of the same battery bought in totaly different time (difference between first time and last time when I bought product containing this accumulator is more than year) and number is allways the same.

Comment: Is it 35x8x3 mm in size?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. Post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Li-ion batteries usually follows the naming convention according to size, so for example an 18650 battery is 18 mm in diameter and 65 mm in length. 0 denotes cylindrical form.

In the past, a tailing 5 wound indicate a prismatic cell but yours doesn't.

Anyhow, my best educated guess is that 35 denotes the length, 08 the width and 3 the thickness and all measurements in millimeters.

[image]